# Strange behavior on ComboBox when playing with focus and popup.visible

Tags: qt, focus, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a strange behavior that is annoying me when I try to do this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        color: "green"
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height
        anchors.right : parent.right


        ComboBox {
            id:combo
            popup.visible: combo.activeFocus
            model: [ "Banana", "Apple", "Coconut" ]
        }

    }
    CheckBox {
        id:check
    }
}
```

If I click on the `CheckBox`  and then on the`ComboBox` , the`ComboBox.popup`  **will appears during 1 ms and then disapears**.
I don't understand why because `activeFocus = true`

Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: You selected something, so popup.close() will be called, setting popup.visible = false. What do you expect?

Comment: What do you mean ? I selected the `ComboBox`: I click on the `CheckBox`. Then I click on the `ComboBox`. So I selected the `ComboBox`, so the focus is now on the `ComboBox`. But if doubleclick on the `ComboBox` instead of just clicking, it will works fine.

Comment: This kind of use case was simply never thought of. What I can imagine that happens there is that ComboBox receives a mouse event and passes it to the base class implementation that handles focus. The control gains  active focus and boom, the popup is opened. Then the execution returns back to the mouse event handler of ComboBox, which toggles the visibility of the popup as it should under normal circumstances, and so the popup is closed right away. It can be easily fixed by querying the visibility of the popup before doing the focus handling. Feel free to report a bug.

Comment: @jpnurmi: That is the conclusion I draw as well. But I don't see, where there is a bug to be fixed. The only thing you could do is *handling the mouse event first* - which would help here (by overwriting the binding of `popup.visible`) to keep it shown. But as the only thing that effectively changes here, is that the `popup.visible: combo.activeFocus` will be unbound, you can save the time, and just erase that line. If you want to have only one function to show it from externaly, create a `function show() { forceActiveFocus(); popup.open() }` and call this instead of `forceActiveFocus()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is to be expected, if you follow the chain of events leading to it:

1. You click on the `ComboBox`
2. The `ComboBox` gains `activeFocus`
3. The `ComboBox.popup` becomes `visible`
4. The click is handled, to toggle the visiblity -> the `ComboBox` becoms invisible.

Remove the line

```
popup.visible: combo.activeFocus
```

and you are fine.

Control the visibility via `open()` and `close()` instead.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my problem. It is when I click **on** the `ComboBox` that the `Popup` will appears and then disapears. This will occur **only** if I clicked on the `CheckBox` before clicking on the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Yep, I mixed something up, while reading. Now this should explain what goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your explantion, I will try it tomorrow or Monday, depend of when i can work on the project

Comment: So I use `open` to control the visibility and it almost work as I want. The only problem is that if I use `open` to show the `Popup`, the popup will appears but there won't be any `Highlight Rectangle` on the current value that is selected by the `ComboBox` . But if I open the `ComboBox` by clicking on the `ComboBox` itself, the `Highlight Rectangle` will be on the current value. Do you have any idea why ?